# Add custom "Open With" when I right click on a file name in Android SDK Project Explorer

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3

I want to add an option to open a file with Notepad++ in the Open With option when I right click on a file in the Android SDK Project Manager. Is it possible to customize this menu? I t looks like they do provide an `Open With > Other` option and then browse for the desired text editor, but I want Notepad++ to appear directly on the list so that I don't have to go looking for it every time. Is it possible to customize this menu?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such functionality to add your customize programs for viewing the files in Android SDK explorer.

The problem with this is that when Eclipse doesn't know what to do with a given file, it opens it with the so called "System Editor", which actually is... whatever your OS says it is, hence the "rolling dice effect". I don't think you can tell the OS to use Eclipse as the default editor (though I didn't try; anyway I wonder why anyone would actually want to do it), so you have two alternatives: either install an eclipse plug-in to manage the kind of file you want to edit (like e.g. pyDev for python), or go to `Window > Preferences > Editors > File Associations` and associate your file extensions to the built-in text editor in Eclipse.

For more details check [HERE](http://www.cisforcoding.com/?p=11)